# No checkout used in Azure pipeline starter yaml template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

This code is a starter template provided in Azure Devops:

```
trigger:
- dev

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python27:
      python.version: '2.7'
    Python35:
      python.version: '3.5'
    Python36:
      python.version: '3.6'
    Python37:
      python.version: '3.7'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: |
    pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
    pytest
  displayName: 'pytest'
```

If pytest is being run on the source code, why is the [checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines) definition not being used? If checkout is not specified, is that the same as `- checkout: none`? I would have thought `- checkout: self` would be needed here?

For my understanding, what is the default behaviour here? i.e. how would I use `checkout` for the same behaviour as this template?

Comment: Look at the documentation. `checkout: self` is implicit if not specified.